# How to configure multiple test suites with Angular and angular.json

Tags: testing, angular-cli

I would like to set up separate commands in my Angular 10 project to run different suites of tests. For example, to have different suites for unit tests and integration tests.

I can see the `test` configuration in the `angular.json` file, and that it uses `src/test.ts` as the entry / main. In the `src/test.ts` there is a line that finds all of the files with `.spec.ts` endings.

What I would like to do is to set up 2 separate test configurations so that I can execute command line commands with the intent of:

```
ng test --unit
```

or

```
ng test --integration
```

The unit tests would pick up all files ending in `.spec.ts`, while the integration tests would pick up files ending in `.int.ts`.

However, I think there can be only one test configuration in the `angular.json` file.

Is there a way that I can achieve the above or something similar?